# Azure Managed Identity from within a docker container running locally

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am running a docker container consisting of a asp.net core 2.2 api. This api needs access to Azure key vault and I have signed in into Visual studio with a user that has the right access policies on the Key Vault to retrieve secrets. However, when I use visual studio tools for docker to debug the container, this particular sign in does not seem to propogate inside the container running locally. But when i run the application locally(without running it in docker container) the asp net core configuration provider seems to pick up my visual studio login. Any pointers on this is helpful

Comment: Hmm, haven't tried this particular scenario. I'm not entirely sure how the VS provider works under the hood, but an alternative provider used in other environments is the Az CLI. It'll attempt to run something like `az get-access-token` as one of the possible options for getting the token. Maybe that could be gotten to work somehow?

Comment: I tried running az login on my laptop before starting a debugging session but no luck

Comment: I am going to try mounting `localappdata` folder inside the container and set an environment variable `LOCALAPPDATA` that points to the mounted path within the container. I am on my way to work will port later on if this worked

Comment: No luck with that

Comment: From the research that I have done, if you are not running in Azure or a machine that has local MSI endpoint set up, then you are out of luck(atleast, i am not sure if there is a way to solve this). However, in this scenario, I had to set user secret using `dotnet user-secret`. This then was mounted as a volume by visual studio tools for docker in the docker compose override file

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with docker and MSI on my mac. I ended up doing the following workaround:

First get an access token from CLI and set it to environment (and remember pass it to docker)

```
export ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource=https://vault.azure.net | jq -r .accessToken)
```

In the code, pick it up if token is in environment:

```
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient;
var accessToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ACCESS_TOKEN");
if (accessToken!=null)
{
   keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
       async (string a, string r, string s)=> accessToken);
}
else
{
   var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
   keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
      new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
          azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read this post ~ month ago. I was looking for answer on the similar question. I found that Docker can run Kubernetes and there is AAD-Pod-Identity https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity which doesn't work for Docker Kubernetes. I forked their repository and make modification for mic component. Now it works for Docker Kubernetes, not sure whether Azure team has plans get these modifications on board or not.

You can get detailed instructions how to get things running here:
https://github.com/Wallsmedia/aad-pod-identity

Answer (score 0):

One more option, which avoids secret injection, is to use the device code authentication flow to obtain a user_impersonation access token. The downside, the developer must manually complete the flow every time the container starts up.

These posts outline the process,
https://joonasw.net/view/device-code-flow
https://blog.simonw.se/getting-an-access-token-for-azuread-using-powershell-and-device-login-flow/
Use the powershell clientId to avoid registering a new tenant app. Works like a charm.