# Azure CLI Login within Docker Container

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have successfully created a docker image that runs inside a docker container.  The container successfully executes the image (a .NET app) but the image crashes shortly after startup because it encounters an error with Azure Services.  The reason is because the docker container is attempting to access Azure Services to fetch an authorization token (to fetch secrets from a key vault) and does not have authority to do so.

I should note that it is possible to run the app locally outside of a container via the Azure CLI after using `az login` to verify my credentials.  Then, when the app is started via Azure CLI, it is 'allowed' to access Azure Services to get autho tokens and consequentially fetch data from my key vault.

Would like to know if there is a way to run an `az login` script with credentials inside a docker container before the .NET app image executes, so that I can start the application from within the Azure CLI (inside the container) after my credentials have been verified.  I have looked through the documentation and have not seen a way to configure something like this.

Comment: why not to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ?

Comment: @DavidNoreña we used this solution in an older version of our app but it required that we maintained a local config for this setup.  We're moving away from local configs so we will have to fetch everything from an external service.  But this is definitely a valid solution for people who don't mind local configs.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: yeah, you can save the service principal and the keyvault url as local configurations, or you can inject them as environmnet variables. Don't take it bad, but that's a really bad design. If you are using Kubernetes is even easier with something like this https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity, but if you see you accepted answer you still have to deal with local configurations.

Comment: @DavidNoreña no offense taken at all, I appreciate the feedback!  The end goal is to run this all via Azure Devops. . .everything will be injected in the pipeline (env vars).  However, I am now trying to figure out how to actually install Azure CLI inside my docker container, then run `az login` with my injected service principle env vars, then start my app after the login.  There are scant resources on this online and the actual documentation about installing docker via CLI does not work inside a container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the Azure CLI and login inside the container, you need to install the Azure CLI inside the container, then login with an non-interactive model. I would recommend the service principal. You can take a look at the command:

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-url> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>
```

For more details, see [Create an Azure service principal with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest). After login, then you can start your application as need.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesXu.  I'm having trouble finding examples of installing Azure CLI inside an actual container before I install the image/app that I need to run.  Do you know of any examples I might be able to follow?

Comment: @yummylumpkins Yeah, you can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest). Select one according to your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 options which don't require Azure CLI in the container, [Azure Managed Identity from within a docker container running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880080/azure-managed-identity-from-within-a-docker-container-running-locally),

- inject an access token into the container using ENV variable
- use device authentication flow to obtain an access token

Answer (score 1):

I read this answers a while ago. I was looking for the similar solution but using the service principal. I found that Docker can run Kubernetes and there is AAD-Pod-Identity https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity which can do work for me, but it doesn't work for Docker Kubernetes. I forked their Go repository and make modification for mic component. Now it works for Docker Kubernetes, not sure whether Azure team has plans get these modifications on board or not.

You can get detailed instructions how to get things running here: https://github.com/Wallsmedia/aad-pod-identity

Azure CLI would not work for a Docker, because you have setup Azure CLI and login and then run your application.